# YouTube iFrame API Doesn't Load Video on iPhone

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm receiving an error about a header set within the YouTube iFrame API. I do not believe that this was happening previously.

```
Refused to set unsafe header "Origin"
Wdwww-embed-player.js:225:275
$dwww-embed-player.js:228:375
(anonymous function)www-embed-player.js:1267
Jmwww-embed-player.js:870:162
Gqwww-embed-player.js:1266:557
wrwww-embed-player.js:1302:197
(anonymous function)F1CbO4TLzgI:9:14691
```

This only appears to be happening on iPhone (both in Chrome and Safari). I'm on the latest iOS (9.2.1)

This is the code where the last error occurs:

```
//ln 1503
function Wd(a, b, c, d, e, f, h) {
    function k() {
        4 == (l && "readyState"in l ? l.readyState : 0) && b && nc(b)(l)
    }
    var l = Ud && Ud();
    if (!("open"in l))
        return null;
    "onloadend"in l ? l.addEventListener("loadend", k, !1) : l.onreadystatechange = k;
    c = (c || "GET").toUpperCase();
    d = d || "";
    l.open(c, a, !0);
    f && (l.responseType = f);
    h && (l.withCredentials=!0);
    f = "POST" == c;
    if (e = Xd(a, e))
        for (var n in e)
            l.setRequestHeader(n, e[n]), "content-type" == n.toLowerCase() && (f=!1);
    f && l.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    l.send(d);
    return l
}
```

Here is my code to load the video:

```
var yt = document.createElement('div'),
    _this = this,
    id = this.videoID;

$(yt).attr('id', id);
this.container.append(yt);

this.el = new YT.Player(id, {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    playerVars: {
        'autoplay': 1,
        'controls': 0,
        'search': 0,
        'showinfo': 0,
        'autohide': 1,
        'rel': 0,
        'html5': 1
    },
    videoId: this.videoID,
    events: {
        'onReady': function(e) { _this.loadComplete(e); },
        'onStateChange': function(e) { _this.stateChanged(e); },
        'onError': function(e) { _this.error(e); }
    }
});

this.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    _this.core.debug.log('YOUTUBE', 'CHECKTIMEOUT', _this);
    if (!_this.isLoaded) {
        _this.error();
    }
}, TIMEOUT);
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also just a note... this error is not occurring on desktop browsers.

Comment: Can you provide a full jsfiddle example so I can test on an iPhone?

Comment: It doesn't appear that jsfiddle is working for even a basic embed on my iphone... https://jsfiddle.net/n7gvsqb9/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with my own code. The error is occurring but I think the video will still load OK.

You can see the error even occurs on the YouTube iFrame API demo page, but the video works.